# What is causing this sickness in my dog and how should it be treated?

Tags: dogs, diseases, medicines, veterinarian, infections

The Shih Tzu x Maltese Mix is 2.5 years old. Male, not neutered, usually very high energy.

Day 0:

- exhibited some tiredness and chewing of paw - was presumed by vet to be grass seed stuck in the paw

Days 2 - 5:

- Loxicom (dog ibuprofen) administered. No diarrhoea, bleeding or sickness during this course.

Day 6:

- furtively eating grass, refusing all food and treats, little energy and did not pass stool until later on when it was minimal and slimy.
- Worsened in the afternoon with farting and looking uncomfortable and couldn't do a walk. He ate three teaspoons of food. Still reactive.
- Slept in the night but was found to have soiled himself the following
  morning.

Day 7:

- sick for the first time.
- Farting again in the garden, drinking lots of water and
  trying to eat more grass. He was very sick again with white foam and
  containing grass and we contacted the vets.
- some rectal bleeding.
- Saw the vets at 16:30 and it was suggested we take him straight to the hospital.

The diagnosis and feedback from the hospital is very confused hence this forum question:

- 'bad' bloods, taken twice due to them not matching briefly recovering/happy behaviour.
- Some form of fluids given, attempts being made at food (primarily syringed), alongside antibiotics
- fluid was drained from digestive system
- Potential damage from the prescribed medicine (notes now rule against ever using it again with this dog).
- temperature and (low) blood pressure are fluctuating
- scans show a shadow that is likely to be food
- Shallow breathing and responsiveness calmed/improved with some attention from family members

There is no clear diagnosis or prognosis from the vet so far. Here are the possible causes I've shortlisted from discussion and limited research:

- reaction to Loxicom
- pancreatitis
- foreign object (but why not show up in the scan?)
- parasite
- infection (should have been clear from bloods?)
- lack of fibre

Please advise what possible causes and treatments might be relevant to this case?

Comment: I will provide further breakdown of bloods, temperature, scans when able.

Comment: it sounds like your dog has been poisoned,if this is the case you need to get your dog treated by the vet.

Comment: My first thought was poison, possibly something that causes cramps in the digestive system. That's why he ate so much grass. He felt that something is wrong in his stomach or intestines and tried to purge it by inducing vomiting via eating grass.

Comment: Prime symptom is fluid build up in the stomach it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem eventually cleared up by visiting the vets after he was put on fluids and under observation until he began eating and drinking again (in slowly increasing amounts). It is likely the dosage, painkiller itself, and/or being in an unfamiliar environment exacerbated or caused the issue. No specific cause or treatment was identified beyond wait-and-see.